# Python says that they cant have a "Visible" index

Tags: python, string, class

I have a student who is trying to make a text based game in Python 3 a-la Zork and is working with classes. The error he's getting is that the dictionary keys are strings, and Python says that they cant have a "Visible" index.

Here's the code he has written for the class...

```
class see():
    def look(room):
        objects = room["Objects"].keys()
        items = room["Items"]

        print(room["Description"])
        print("In the room you see:")
        for i in objects:
            if room["Objects"[i["Visible"]]]:
                print(room["Objects"[i["Description"]]])
        for i in items:
            if room["Items"[i["Visible"]]]:
                for j in game.ITEM:
                    if i == j:
                        print(game.ITEM[i["Description"]])
                for j in game.WEAPON:
                    if i == j:
                        print(game.WEAPON[i["Description"]])
```

When the script is run, he gets the error that it needs to be an integer. What's the fix here? I'm new to Python myself and am scurrying to try and help. I can post the game code that calls the class if that helps.

Comment: Are you sure this code is correct? `room["Items"[i["Visible"]]]` You're indexing the string `Items` there. Also here: `room["Objects"[i["Visible"]]]`.

Comment: No. The code was broken. As Mu pointed out below, the bracketing needed to be changed for it to function properly. Thanks for taking the time to help. It's much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is incorrect (the brackets are not closing properly):

```
room["Objects"[i["Visible"]]]
```

Do this instead:

```
room["Objects"][i]["Visible"]
```

Similarly, you also need to correct `room["Items"[i["Visible"]]]` to `room["Items"][i]["Visible"]` and `game.ITEM[i["Description"]]` to `game.ITEM[i]["Description"]` and so on..

As pointed out already, when you do `"Items"[i["Visible"]]]`, that tries to index from the string and hence throws up the error.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much. This solved it perfectly. It's been a high speed learning curve for me as much as the students. A resource like this is invaluable. I'll no doubt be posting again.